# How do I order an array of floating point numbers using a criteria other than size, using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, arrays

For example, I have an array of floating point numbers:

```
float[] numbers = new float[] { 1, 34, 65, 23, 56, 8, 5, 3, 234 };
```

If I use:

```
Array.Sort(numbers);
```

Then the array is sorted by the size of the number.

I want to sort the numbers by another criteria, so element A should go before element B if f(A) < f(B), rather than the usual of A < B.

So, for example, If I want to sort them according to there value modulo 5. The array would become:

```
5, 65, 1, 56, 3, 8, 23, 34, 234
```

I think it can be done through LINQ, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I want to sort the numbers by another criteria, so element A should go before element B if f(A) < f(B)

```
numbers.OrderBy(f);
```

Comment: +1. Enumerable.OrderBy docs can be found here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx

Comment: Implementation for your requirement using Enumerable.OrderBy would be `numbers.OrderBy(f => f % 5);`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Comparison<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) overload of Array.Sort:

```
Array.Sort(numbers, (a,b) => (a % 5).CompareTo(b % 5));
```

Comparison<T> is just a delegate, so you can use lambdas / anonymous methods. It's not LINQ, but I think it's what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ:

```
var result = from n in numbers orderby n % 5, n select n;
var sortedNumbers = result.ToArray();
```

Alternately:

```
var result = numbers.OrderBy(n => n % 5).ThenBy(n => n);
```

Ordering by mod 5, then by the number yields the results in the order you specified.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) ;-) and let an List sort the elements for you with your custom comparer.

Answer (score 0):

More Brute even! I suggest you to make an Array of f(x) and then sort on that!