# Float sorting with Array.Sort()

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, sorting

I need in C# to sort some distances in some objects which are in `float`. I use delegate and `Array.Sort` to sort them but it seems that I can't use `float`.

How can I keep the precision of those float when converting to `int`?

Is it possible to use `Array.Sort` with `float` instead of `int` in return?

Without using LINQ.

Comment: You can't convert float to int without losin precision. show as some sample of your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I order an array of floating point numbers using a criteria other than size, using LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451889/how-do-i-order-an-array-of-floating-point-numbers-using-a-criteria-other-than-si)

Comment: Btw, although the title of that question mentions LINQ there are a number of correct answers that do use Comparer or Comparison instead of LINQ that should work just as well for you.

Comment: Why don't you want to use LINQ?

Comment: I saw a lot of posts with LINQbut I can't use LINQ.

Comment: @MaT: `but I can't use Linq` Which framework are you using since i think its an older version?

Comment: Why can't you just use Array.Sort? The answer to your question is "Yes, It is possible"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Array.Sort<T>(T[] array, Comparison<T> comparison)` is not restricted to any type as long as you provide correct comparison delegate. Comparison delegate should return integer value containing the result of compare operation, not a value to be compared with something. For example, if you have class `X` with `float` property `Property`, you can sort them like this:

```
public sealed class X
{
    public float Property { get; set; }
}

static void Test()
{
    var arr = new X[]
    {
        new X { Property = 5.5f },
        new X { Property = 2.5f },
        new X { Property = 6.5f },
        new X { Property = 1.2f },
    };
    Array.Sort(arr, (a, b) => a.Property.CompareTo(b.Property));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use LINQ OrderBy extension method

```
var arr = new[] { 1.3f, 1.4f };
arr.OrderBy( a => a ).ToArray();
```

Comment: he added it later. Ok, I'm sorry, no limitations was given at first

Answer (score 2):

You could use LINQ?

```
arrayOfFloats = arrayOfFloats.OrderBy(x => x);
```

Answer (score 2):

The best variant is to use radixsort, see more at

[Is there a good radixsort-implementation for floats in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685035/is-there-a-good-radixsort-implementation-for-floats-in-c-sharp)

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using some older .Net version since in one of your comments you have asked that you do not want to use LINQ.

In that case **Yes it is possible use `Array.Sort`**

```
float[] myfloatarray = new float[5];

Array.Sort(myfloatarray);
```

This will use

```
Array.Sort<T>(T[] array);
```

This does not use any LINQ only generics and is available in .Net 2.0.

[Read about Array.Sort here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're confusing the "in" type `T` which is allowed to be anything, with the return type of the `Comparison<T>` delegate which must be `int`?

This works fine:

```
float[] arr = { 2.3f, 1.1f, 9.0f, 6.6f, };
Array.Sort(arr, (x, y) => SomeMethodReturningInt(x, y));
```

The second parameter to `Sort` is a `Comparison<float>` in this case. In the lambda, `x` and `y` are `float`s.